# Calling a constructor function | why does "this" keyword return undefined?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm playing around with objects and constructors and am curious why I can't    execute: person(5,10). The parameters are passed to the person function but then the variable assignment disappears and I get the "cannot set property "age" of undefined" error in chrome.

```
"use strict"

function person(age, height){
this.age = age;
this.height = height;
this.calculate = function(){
     var newHeight = this.height * 2;
     console.log(newHeight);
    }
}
person(5,10);
```

Comment: use `var p = new person(5, 10);`

Comment: You need to initialize the object

Comment: To use a function as a constructor you have to invoke it with "new" operator. This would work
    "new person(5,10);"

Comment: @11thdimension do you know why you can't just execute it like I've written? I'm not trying to create a new object, I just noticed I couldn't run the code like written. To me it seems that person is a valid function definition and therefore "person(5,10)" should log 20 to the console. Thanks.

Comment: *"To me it seems that person is a valid function definition and therefore "person(5,10)" should log 20 to the console."* What do you think `this.age = age` is doing? What do you think `this` is? Why do you expect the function to log something? It doesn't contain a `console.log` statement. `console.log` is in the body if the inner function which is never called. *"I'm not trying to create a new object"* But you just said in your question: *"I'm playing around with objects and constructors"*.

Comment: @FelixKling I think `this.age` refers to the `window` object, and if that's true (which it might not be) `this` should not evaluate to `undefined` (I think). If it was the window object though, `window.age` would be `undefined` which would make sense. Thanks for catching the `console.log` part.

Comment: *"I think `this.age` refers to the window object"* I guess you mean `this` is the `window` object. As I said in my answer, if your code runs in strict mode, `this` is `undefined`. And since you are getting this specific error, it seems your code does run in strict mode. *"If it was the window object though, window.age would be undefined which would make sense."* Well, after your function ran, `window.age` would be 5.

Comment: @Stu, check my answer below for explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confusion comes because a function can be used as a callable function and an object constructor both. 
Good practice is to not mix up both forms, meaning a constructor function should not be used as a callable function.
In general constructor function has first letter capitalized (just by convention to give a hint to the reader of the code). 
Object based languages in general implicitly provide the reference to the object on which a method is called. In Javascript this reference is "this" keyword inside the function.
Consider the following code.

```
var obj = {
    sum: 0,
    add: function(increment) {
        this.sum += increment;
        return this.sum;
    }
};
```

When we call obj.add(2), interpreter or compiler in any other object based language will do an internal calling of method add as following

```
add(arguments..., [this=obj]) {
    //this is the obj reference inside the method
}
add(arguments, obj);
```

Above is just a pseudo code, last parameter is hidden from us and we don't need to pass it explicitly, this parameter is the reference to the actual object on which the add() method was invoked and is available via "this" keyworkd.

In general when we declare a function outside an Object scope, it becomes method (Edited** if not nested in another function) of the global object ( normally window object). So it's invokation will pass global object as the "this" reference. In strict mode default global object is undefined and any operations that have to be done on the window or global object are to be done explicitly. So that we do not modify the global object inadvertently.

When we call a function as a constructor like below

```
var p1 = new Person();
```

Interpreter will execute a code similar to

```
var newObj = new Object();
Person(arguments..., [this=newObj]) {
    //this is the newObj reference inside the method
    return this;
}
Person(arugments..., newObj);
```

I hope it's a bit clearer now.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to craft such a good reply. It definitely helps. I was using strict mode I just didn't realize it because I copied and pasted my code into an existing document.

Comment: *"In general when we declare a function outside an Object scope, it becomes method of the global object ( normally window object). So it's invokation will pass global object as the "this" reference."* That is incorrect. Just think about nested functions: `function foo() { function bar() { console.log(this); }; bar();}; foo()`. `bar` is not global, it's not a property of the global object, yet `this` refers to the global object. *" In strict mode default global object is undefined"* No, the global object is always an object. In strict mode `this` doesn't default to the global object.

Comment: That's correct, accurate way of saying that would be if a function is not invoked on any object by using (dot) operator, it's invoked on global object. Only functions which are not contained in any other function become methods of global object. In any other case (nested functions) they just act as if they are invoked on the global object without becoming a member of global object.

Answer (score 1):

> I get the "cannot set property "age" of undefined" error in chrome.

When you call a function in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) is `undefined`. It  seems you want to call the function as constructor, with `new`:

```
new person(5, 10)
```

[Learn more about constructors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript#Custom_objects).

---

Note: The convention is to capitalize the name of constructor functions.

Comment: Good he's using strict mode, otherwise he wouldn't even have noticed the mistake :-)